Redis AOF rewrite memory consumption
We have an issue with redis where very short memory spikes cause OOMKill.
Since we have maxmemory config set we believe that that issue is caused by AOF rewrite.
What's the general recommendation for AOF rewrite memory overhead?

When rewriting AOF file, Redis does a fork with copy-on-write. So in some edge case, you it might double your memory consumption. In order to run Redis safely, you'd better set maxmemory to be at most half of your total memory.

Thanks, is there any reference / doc supporting that?

Check this on how AOF rewrite work.

I understand how it works, but I can't see a record of maxmemory 50%

You can check how fork works, although copy-on-write might not cost so much memory.
